# How to write 2 lists of items in 2 columns instead of 2 arrays?

Tags: python

I ran my code and got 2 lists like this:

[image]

and what I need to do is put them in a .csv file.
but I got an output that looks ugly like this:

[image]

The correct one should be like this:
[image]

So what should I do to solve that problem?

code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import urllib
import re
import csv

def main():
    html = urlopen("https://www.realestate.com.au/rent/with-1-bedroom-in-perth+-+greater+region%2c+wa/list-1?maxBeds=1&source=location-search").read().decode('utf-8')
    csvfile=open('price.csv','w',newline='')
    #### check
    ##print(price(html))
    ##print(postcode(html))
    #### end check
    writer=csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(['Postcode','Price'])
    data=[price(html),postcode(html)]
    writer.writerows(data)
    csvfile.close()

def price(page):
    priceTextReg=re.compile(r"priceText\">(.+?)<")
    priceText = re.findall(priceTextReg,page)
    p1=[]
    for i in range(20):  ## we just need the first 20 items
        priceReg=re.compile(r"\d+")
        price=re.findall(priceReg,priceText[i])
        p1.append(price[0])  
    return p1

def postcode(page):
    postcodeTextReg=re.compile(r"alt=.+?, WA (.+?)' title=")
    postcodeText=re.findall(postcodeTextReg,page)
    p2=[]
    for i in range(20):
        postcode=postcodeText[i]
        p2.append(postcode)
    return p2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip`. Change:

```
data=[price(html),postcode(html)]
```

to:

```
data=zip(price(html),postcode(html))
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the line:

```
data=[price(html),postcode(html)]
```

With it:

```
data = zip(price(html), postcode(html))
```

Answer (score 0):

can you use a dictionary? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html
set the key as the postCode and the value as the price

Answer (score 0):

Let me introduce you here to [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) from [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html). Assign your lists to the dataframe like this and save it to a csv finally!

```
import pandas as pd

finalDf = pd.DataFrame(
    {'postcode': p2,
     'price': p1
})

finalDf.to_csv('your_file.csv')
```